# Can I use school subdomain to raise personal .com domain ranking?

Tags: seo

As a grad student at UPenn, I have access to the subdomain `seas.upenn.edu/~lindsb/`, in which I built a simple personal website. This domain showed up in the top 5 results on Google when I typed in "Ben Lindsay", I assume because it belongs to `upenn.edu`, a relatively well-respected website. I assume this because I did nothing intentional to try to improve SEO and probably did not do anything magical by accident. About a year ago, I moved my site to `benjlindsay.com`, which looks much nicer than the previous domain name, but it doesn't show up anywhere on a Google search for my name. I just put in a `meta` tag in my UPenn domain that redirects to my newer domain name today.

My question is, is there some way to make use of the UPenn subdomain to get `benjlindsay.com` to show up in the top 5?

Comment: Not really short of one link. Work on your own site by creating content making it relevant. Consider a Google+ account and linking it to your site. Use schema.org mark-up for your posts and contact information. Gain an audience then brand your name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want search engines to take notice that your site  moved, you need to implement `301` redirects. In general, bots do not follow redirects via meta tags.

Another option would be to use [canonical tag](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/139066?hl=en), however keep in mind that `301` is better.

As for the ranking aspect in general - just stick to normal website development, give it some time, add some social signals from Twitter, G+, LinkedIn, GitHub (for example, your public LinkedIn profile shows the correct link, but GitHub still links to the `edu` domain).

On your personal site, make one `about me` page and implement [person schema](https://developers.google.com/schemas/reference/types/Person). Link back to your social footprint. Sample code:

```
<script type="application/ld+json">
{
  "@context": "http://www.schema.org",
  "@type": "person",
  "name": "Something Something",
  "url": "https://example.com/",
  "image": "https://example.com/images/me.jpg",
  "sameAs" : [
    "https://www.twitter.com/someid",
    "https://www.twitter.com/anotherid",
    "https://plus.google.com/+someID/posts",
    "https://www.linkedin.com/in/someid",
    "https://github.com/someid"
  ],
  "jobTitle": "Something",
  "telephone": "+1234567890",
  "worksFor": "Some Corp, Inc.",
  "description": "Some description"
}
 </script>
```

Getting a rank for `[first name last name]` with exact match domain should be rather easy.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed info! I tried implementing a 301 redirect with a .htaccess file, but it didn't work. Maybe I'll try that again. Thanks for letting me know my GitHub was out of date.

Comment: Your `.htaccess` may be fine - your host may have something turned off in config. It is common for sysadmins on such hosts to instruct httpd to ignore user-made `.htaccess` files. It varies, you should check with your sysadmin what is allowed. They do it precisely because `edu` domains are high-profile and carry high value for search engine spammers :). If this is the case, try fiddling with PHP or anything that will allow you to customize headers before a response to http request is sent.

Comment: I'm too much of a novice to follow the fiddling with PHP suggestion...would this be something that could improve my new site's rank even if web crawlers are the only things that see my `.edu` subdomain, or would that only benefit if humans are still going to the `.edu` subdomain? If it's the former, then please expand on that or point me to some resources. If it's the latter, I'll just leave my meta tag redirect in place.